# In python3, how do I choose to encode in order to be able to read the page correctly

Tags: html, python-3.x, encode, html-encode

I am trying to use the following command to get the page's source code

> requests.get("website").text

But I get an error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xe6' in position 356: illegal multibyte sequence

Then I tried to change the page code to utf-8

> requests.get("website").text.encode('utf-8')

But in addition to English will become the following form

> \xe6°\xb8\xe4\xb9\x85\xe6\x8f\x90\xe4\xbe\x9b\xe5\x85\x8dè\xb4\xb9VPN\xe5\xb8\x90\xe5\x8f·\xe5\x92\x8c\xe5\x85\x8dè\xb4\xb

How can I do?
Thank you for your help

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344416/comparing-two-strings-works-on-windows-but-fails-on-linux

Comment: @jingjie But I'am Windows

Comment: erhm sorry, can't really help :/

Comment: @jingjie All right,but thank you very much.

Comment: How about pasting the relevant piece of your code for starters?

Comment: @zwer OK,I did it

Answer (score 0):

You can query the encoding of the `requests.Response` object by accessing its `Response.content` attribute.

Whenever you call `requests.Response.text`, the response object uses `requests.Response.encoding` to decode the bytes.

This may, however, not always be the correct encoding, hence you sometimes have to set it manually by looking it up in the `content` attribute, since websites usually specify the encoding there, if it's not `utf-8` or similar (this is from experience, I'm not sure if this is actual standard behavior).

[See more on `requests.Response` contents here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)

Comment: Through this method, I found the page encoding ISO-8859-1, but after changing the code, still can not correctly display other languages

Comment: Yes, so you should know that the encoding is `latin-1` - use that to update `requests.Response.encoding`, and it should work, no?

Comment: I changed the code into latin-1 but in fact it dosen't work

Comment: You mean you used `.decode('latin-1')` on the relevant bytes object?