# Comparing two strings works on windows but fails on linux

Tags: java, unit-testing, character-encoding

I have written a unit test, which controls if there are any encoding problems with german letters( ä,ö,ß,etc.)

```
@Test
public void testBodyWithDefaultCharset() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    when(backendDefinition.getProperty(BackendDetailsEnum.MAIL_CHARSET.getName())).thenReturn(null);
    Charset defaultCharset  = Charset.defaultCharset();
    when(packet.getPayload()).thenReturn(defaultCharset.encode("ÄÖÜäöüß").array());

    final String mailText = classUnderTest.prepareMailText(backendDefinition, packet);

    assertThat(mailText, is(equalTo("ÄÖÜäöüß")));
}
```

This test passes in windows pc but fails on jenkins, which is a linux environment. The error message is as follows;

```
Expected: is "ÄÖÜäöüß"
but: was "???????"
```

My question is, is it wrong to compare mailText with "ÄÖÜäöüß"? I thougt I don't need to state any encoding when I compare two strings.

Comment: `Charset.defaultCharset()` sounds suspicious. Are you able to select UTF-8?

Comment: default charsets will probably differ between unix and windows, i'd expect windows to be `ISO-1250 (Windows)` but i wouldn't really know which one to expect on unix... can you try with UTF-8 ?

Comment: The default Charset might not be the same in your two environments, hence the different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the assertion line as follows and it worked.

```
assertThat(mailText, is(equalTo(new String("ÄÖÜäöüß".getBytes(defaultCharset)))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be that your file encoding and stuff is defined differently on Windows then on Linux? It sounds like it is a difference in the file-encoding.

You may try to explicit set encoding in the .bashrc or by using the `locale`-program in Linux (example with UTF-8):

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

What is the output of:

`locale`?

Any different than the one expected?

Also do check which Charset the `defaultCharset()` is using. Try outputting the value on both Windows / Linux.